# Java Spring Boot multi-tenancy but with ONE common database for a SPECIFIC entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

Java Spring Boot (3.0.6) Multi-tenancy but with one common database for a specific entity

Hi! First of all, I'm pretty new to the Java (Spring Boot) world (coming from .NET), and I have the following question / problem:

One ouf our clients wants a multi-tenant (AAD auth) application, where Reservation entity records come from a common database (let's say db_common), but all the User records are stored in a separate, tenant-specific database.

So it is the database approach, according to this: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy

Now I'v managed to solve resolving the tenant id, from the authenticated JWT token, and I've solved the multi-tenancy with a TenantConnectionProvider which extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.

**See the code below:**

The HibernateConfig class (entityManagerFactory bean):

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
                                                                       DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       TenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantIdentifierResolver) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("myapp.api");

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);

        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        jpaProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantIdentifierResolver);
        jpaProperties.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);

        jpaProperties.put(Environment.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.class);
        jpaProperties.put(Environment.DIALECT, MariaDBDialect.class);

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

        Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

The tenant connection provider class:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TenantConnectionProvider extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    @Value("${app.database-name-prefix}")
    private String databaseNamePrefix;
    
    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        String useStatement = String.format("USE `%s`;",  databaseNamePrefix + tenantIdentifier);
        connection.createStatement().execute(useStatement);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Now this code works, but I can't make it to work like I described above (reservations should be coming from a common database).

(My first guess is that it is because of the USE statement in the getConnection function, which can be too rough.. and overwrites every other connection provider. Maybe I should do the db selection here differently..)

I'v read, that I could create another connection provider, and annotate it (and the repository, and model classes) with @Primary, and I tried it like so:

```
@Configuration
@Primary
public class CommonDatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource commonDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3308/db_common");
        dataSource.setUsername("***");
        dataSource.setPassword("***");
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory2() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(commonDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("myapp.api"); 
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Entity's header:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Primary
public class Reservation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
... 
...
...
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
@Primary
public interface ReservationRepository extends CrudRepository<Reservation, Long>, ListPagingAndSortingRepository<Reservation, Long> {
    public final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ReservationRepository.class);
   ...
}
```

But it clearly didn't work, cause it still tries to fetch from the tenant's database.

It feels like I'm close to the final solution (or maybe I have to do this totally differently).

I'm using Spring Boot v3.0.6, Java 17, Gradle.

Can anyone not new to this field could point me to the right direction? Can this be done? If yes, how?

Bonus question that is raising: if the above multi-tenant approach would finally work, can I use foreign keys, @ManyToOne, @OneToMany, etc annotations to have relationships between these entities, even though they are in different databases?

Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: Please, read about [3.5 of this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations#:~:text=To%20use%20JPA%20repositories%2C%20we,can%20do%20this%20with%20%40EnableJpaRepositories.&text=Spring%20will%20look%20for%20repositories,packages%20of%20this%20%40Configuration%20class.&text=Also%20note%2C%20that%20Spring%20Boot,Data%20JPA%20on%20the%20classpath.), as it seems to be what you look for. If you still have doubts, please update your question. You are indeed very close, so I think its worth to try it by yourself a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to solve it, first by separating the models/repos into different packages, and setting the proper package locations on the databaseConfigs with EnableJpaRepositories:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = { "to.package" },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory")
```

Now I'm struggling a bit with flyway migrations with multiple datasources, but that's a different question!

Thanks!